# jQuery function makes entire page load twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

For some reason whenever I try to us jquery for tabs in my page it make entire page loads twice. I done everything find problem and if I disable jquery function page loads only once.

It's probably some minor error that I'm failing to see. Every help is greatly appriciated.

Preview is here: http://agroznanost.com/uploads/jednogodisnje-kulture.php

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
        <title>AgroZnanost</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container_16">
            <div class="grid_16 header">
                <div class="grid_3 logo">
                    <img src="images/logo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="grid_3 slogan">Baza podataka uspiješnog<br/>poljoprivrednika</div>
                <div class="grid_10 nav-links omega">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">OTKUPNE<br/><font color="#d3d3d3">CIJENE</font><a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">JEDNOGODIŠNJE<br/><font color="#d3d3d3">KULTURE</font><a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">VIŠEGODIŠNJE<br/><font color="#d3d3d3">KULTURE</font><a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SVE<br/><font color="#d3d3d3">KULTURE</font><a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container_16 bg_img">
            <img src="images/background_jednogod.png" style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:102.3%;">
        </div>
        <div class="container_16">
            <div class="rect_1">
                <div class="colorize">
                    TABLICA NAJISPLATIVIJIH JEDNOGODIŠNJIH</BR>KULTURA U ODNOSU NA TRŽIŠNE CIJENE
                </div>
                <h3 style="text-align:center;">Detaljni prikaz troska i zarade za jednogodisnji nasad krumpira.<br /></h3>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. </div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra </p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
<p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse lacus.</p>
</div>
</div>

    </div>
</div>

        <div class="copyright" style="width:100%">
            <font color="grey" face="helvetica">Copyright: Agroznanost 2014</font>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
  min-width: 960px;
  background-color: #ececec
}
.logo{
padding:0;
margin-top:-7px;

}
.slogan{
font-family:Pristina;
font-size:15px;
color:#acd6e5;
text-align:center;
margin-top:-5px;
}
.nav-links ul{
margin-top:0;
margin-right:15px;
padding:0;
font-family:Rockwell Extra bold;
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
float:right;
font-weight:bold;
height:30px;

}
.nav-links li{
list-style:none;
display:inline;
margin-left:10px;
}
.nav-links li, li a  {
color:#85d2ee;
text-decoration: none; 
display:inline-block; 
margin-right: 5px
}
.nav-links li a:hover {
color:#36c1f4;
}

.header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    /* Adds the transparent background */
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
    /*color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);*/  
}
.copyright {
    width: 105%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:-6px;
    height: 38px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    /* Adds the transparent background */
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
    padding-right:10px;
    /*color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);*/
}
.bg_img{
margin-left:-8px;
margin-top:-8px;
}

.rect_1{
    border: 6px solid #363636;
    padding: 10px 40px; 
    background: #dddddd;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:75%;
}
.colorize{
    background-color:#363636;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    margin-left:-40px;
    margin-top: 18px;
    padding-right:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-family:Comic Sans MS;
    font-size:24px;
}
/* `Container
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.container_16 {
  margin-left:0 auto;
  margin-right:0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

/* `Grid >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12,
.grid_13,
.srednji_rect,
.grid_14,
.grid_15,
.grid_16 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.push_1, .pull_1,
.push_2, .pull_2,
.push_3, .pull_3,
.push_4, .pull_4,
.push_5, .pull_5,
.push_6, .pull_6,
.push_7, .pull_7,
.push_8, .pull_8,
.push_9, .pull_9,
.push_10, .pull_10,
.push_11, .pull_11,
.push_12, .pull_12,
.push_13, .pull_13,
.push_14, .pull_14,
.push_15, .pull_15 {
  position: relative;
}

.grid_16{
    margin-left:-7px;
}

.container_16 .grid_4 {
    width:35%;
  min-width: 430px;
  max-width: 500px;

}
.container_16 .srednji_rect {
width:22%;
min-width:170px;
max-width:500px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_16 .grid_8 {
width:50%;
  min-width: 490px;
  max-width: 495px;
}


.container_16 .grid_12 {
    width:75%;
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 705px;
}


.container_16 .grid_16 {
  width:  100%;
  min-width: 1020px;
  max-width:1366px;
}

/* `Grid >> Children (Alpha ~ First, Omega ~ Last)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.alpha {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.omega {
  margin-right: 0;
}

/* `Grid >> 16 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.container_16 .grid_1 {
   width: 100px; 

}
.container_16 .grid_2 {
  width: 100px;
}

.container_16 .grid_3 {
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 165px;
}

.container_16 .grid_5 {
    width:33%;
  min-width: 380px;
}

.container_16 .grid_6 {
  width: 340px;
}

.container_16 .grid_7 {
  width: 400px;
  float:right;
}
.container_16 .grid_8 {
    width: 50%;
    float:right;
}

.container_16 .grid_9 {
  width: 520px;
}

.container_16 .grid_10 {
    width: 62.5%;
    float:right;
}

.container_16 .grid_11 {
  width: 640px;
}

.container_16 .grid_13 {
  width: 760px;
}

.container_16 .grid_14 {
  width: 820px;
}

.container_16 .grid_15 {
  width: 880px;
}

/* `Prefix Extra Space >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.container_16 .prefix_4 {
  padding-left: 240px;
}


.container_16 .prefix_8 {
  padding-left: 480px;
}


.container_16 .prefix_12 {
  padding-left: 720px;
}

/* `Prefix Extra Space >> 16 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_16 .prefix_1 {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_2 {
  padding-left: 120px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_3 {
  padding-left: 180px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_5 {
  padding-left: 300px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_6 {
  padding-left: 360px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_7 {
  padding-left: 420px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_9 {
  padding-left: 540px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_10 {
  padding-left: 600px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_11 {
  padding-left: 660px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_13 {
  padding-left: 780px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_14 {
  padding-left: 840px;
}

.container_16 .prefix_15 {
  padding-left: 900px;
}

/* `Suffix Extra Space >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.container_16 .suffix_4 {
  padding-right: 240px;
}


.container_16 .suffix_8 {
  padding-right: 480px;
}


.container_16 .suffix_12 {
  padding-right: 720px;
}

/* `Suffix Extra Space >> 16 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_16 .suffix_1 {
  padding-right: 60px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_2 {
  padding-right: 120px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_3 {
  padding-right: 180px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_5 {
  padding-right: 300px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_6 {
  padding-right: 360px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_7 {
  padding-right: 420px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_9 {
  padding-right: 540px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_10 {
  padding-right: 600px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_11 {
  padding-right: 660px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_13 {
  padding-right: 780px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_14 {
  padding-right: 840px;
}

.container_16 .suffix_15 {
  padding-right: 900px;
}

/* `Push Space >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


.container_16 .push_4 {
  left: -240px;
}


.container_16 .push_8 {
  left: 480px;
}


.container_16 .push_12 {
  left: 720px;
}

/* `Push Space >> 16 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_16 .push_1 {
  left: 60px;
}

.container_16 .push_2 {
  left: 120px;
}

.container_16 .push_3 {
  left: 180px;
}

.container_16 .push_5 {
  left: 300px;
}

.container_16 .push_6 {
  left: 360px;
}

.container_16 .push_7 {
  left: 420px;
}

.container_16 .push_9 {
  left: 540px;
}

.container_16 .push_10 {
  left: 600px;
}

.container_16 .push_11 {
  left: 660px;
}

.container_16 .push_13 {
  left: 780px;
}

.container_16 .push_14 {
  left: 840px;
}

.container_16 .push_15 {
  left: 900px;
}

/* `Pull Space >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_16 .pull_4 {
  left: -240px;
}

.container_16 .pull_8 {
  left: -480px;
}

.container_16 .pull_12 {
  left: -720px;
}


/* `Pull Space >> 16 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_16 .pull_1 {
  left: -60px;
}

.container_16 .pull_2 {
  left: -120px;
}

.container_16 .pull_3 {
  left: -180px;
}

.container_16 .pull_5 {
  left: -300px;
}

.container_16 .pull_6 {
  left: -360px;
}

.container_16 .pull_7 {
  left: -420px;
}

.container_16 .pull_9 {
  left: -540px;
}

.container_16 .pull_10 {
  left: -600px;
}

.container_16 .pull_11 {
  left: -660px;
}

.container_16 .pull_13 {
  left: -780px;
}

.container_16 .pull_14 {
  left: -840px;
}

.container_16 .pull_15 {
  left: -900px;
}

/* `Clear Floated Elements
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* http://sonspring.com/journal/clearing-floats */

.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified */

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.container_16:before,
.container_16:after {
  content: '.';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.clearfix:after,
.container_16:after {
  clear: both;
}

/*
  The following zoom:1 rule is specifically for IE6 + IE7.
  Move to separate stylesheet if invalid CSS is a problem.
*/

.clearfix,
.container_16 {
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: Don't just dump you all code here. Narrow down your problem.

Comment: Preview loads only once on my side.

Comment: It loads only once for me (Chrome). What browser do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the main problem but the `<a>` tags are not closed with `</a>` correctly.

In your code :

```
<li><a href="#">.....<a></li>
<li><a href="#">.....<a></li>
<li><a href="#">.....<a></li>
```

should be changed to :

```
<li><a href="#">.....</a></li>
<li><a href="#">.....</a></li>
<li><a href="#">.....</a></li>
```

Hope this helps.